# Gmail HTML5 Feature to "drop" attachments

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I've seen this and I have to admit I'm pretty impressed:

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/S79rfcmEd7I/AAAAAAAAAjo/kdH1eFnHVYA/attachments2.png))</sub>

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/drag-and-drop-attachments-onto-messages.html

I'm almost certain that this is an *HTML 5* feature (it's supported on Chrome and Firefox 3.5), and was wondering if somebody knew how is the browser feature called.

Bonus points for a tutorial/article on how to do something similar!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this may be of help:

http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

For an HTML5 demo of drag-n-drop, check out:

http://html5demos.com/drag-anything

Seems like `dragover`, `dragenter`, `dragexit`, `drop` events + `event.dataTransfer` are how it all works. Putting it together with a multi-part/form ajax POST like the link that dhorn gave is more impressive in my opinion.  I would hope that it could be done a little easier than that.